# How to compare the previous, current and the next element in Excel VBA cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA

I have the following method in Java to find the high-low elements in an array, but I do not know how to do the same on VBA Excel. The problem is with translating the IF to compare the previous, the current and the next element in the array **{if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1] && arr[i] > arr[i - 1])}**, which in the case of Excel is how to find the previous, the current and the next element in a column of cells while the ForEach is running.

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> sequence(int[] arr) {
    System.out.println(" HIGHEST HIGH " + arr.length);
    ArrayList<Integer> relHigh = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> relLow = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> hestHigh = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> lestLow = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int highest = -9999999;
    int lowest = 9999999;
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length - 2; i++) {
        // System.out.println(" I: " + i + " : " + arr[i]);
        if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1] && arr[i] > arr[i - 1]) {
            relHigh.add(arr[i]);
            System.out.println("RelHigh I: " + i + " : " + arr[i]);
            if (arr[i] > highest) {
                hestHigh.add(arr[i]);
                highest = arr[i];
                System.out.println("HH I: " + i + " : " + arr[i]);
            }
        }
        if (arr[i] < arr[i + 1] && arr[i] < arr[i - 1]) {
            relLow.add(arr[i]);
            System.out.println("RelLow I: " + i + " : " + arr[i]);
            if (arr[i] < lowest) {
                lestLow.add(arr[i]);
                lowest = arr[i];
                System.out.println("LL I: " + i + " : " + arr[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return relHigh;
}
```

[image]

```
Sub MaxMin()

Dim myCount As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim relHigh As Double
Dim relLow As Double
Dim hestHigh As Double
Dim lestLow As Double
Dim highest As Double
Dim lowest As Double

Dim Cellx As Range
Dim MyRange As Range
Set MyRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1").Range("A:A").CurrentRegion

Dim previous As Double
Dim current As Double
Dim next As Double

Dim rCell As Range
Dim rRng As Range

Set rRng = Sheets("Hoja1").Range("A1:A15")

For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
    Debug.Print rCell.Address, rCell.Value
    **// Here is where I get lost**
    if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1] && arr[i] > arr[i - 1]) {
Next rCell

End Sub
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: It looks like you're searching for local maxima/minima: your code is pretty straightforward in VBA but no-one here is going to write it out...  In a `For Each c in myRange.Cells` loop (assuming a column of cells), the "previous" is `c.Offset(-1,0)` and "next" is `c.offset(1,0)`

Comment: I just need the part of the IF. I do not know how to get the previous, current and next value. Only that. Thanks anyway

Comment: The only difference in referencing an array is that VBA uses normal brackets, not square ones! And it doesn't use &&.

Comment: But the range in Excel is not an array. Can I say Range("A:A").(i-1), Range("A:A").(i) and Range("A:A").(i+1)? Guess not. That is my question. How to iterate the column and get the 3 values. If you can tell me where to look at, that would be great. Thanks again

Comment: Maybe if you explain a little where your data is located you might get some more specific suggestions.  Also might help to show what you already tried (even if incomplete).  Folks here tend not to like "rewrite this X for me in Y"-type requests.

Comment: Thanks Tim. The Offset(-1,0) is giving me compilation errors, but htank you anyway : If (rCell.Value > rCell.Offset(1, 0).Value) And (rCell.Value > rCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value) Then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign a column of data to an array using [Transpose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.WorksheetFunction.Transpose). You can't add to an array (without re-dimensioning) but you can add to a [Collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/collection-object).

```vb
Function sequence(ByRef rng As Range) As Variant

    ' assign range to array
    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rng.Value2)
  
    Dim relHigh As New Collection, relLow As New Collection
    Dim highestHigh As New Collection, lowestLow As New Collection
    Dim highest As Long, lowest As Long, i As Long
    Dim highestRow As Long, lowestRow As Long

    highest = -9999999
    lowest = 9999999
    ' clear formatting
    rng.Cells.ClearFormats
    rng.Columns(2).Clear

    For i = 2 To UBound(arr) - 1
      
        If (arr(i) > arr(i + 1)) And (arr(i) > arr(i - 1)) Then
            relHigh.Add arr(i)
            'System.out.println("RelHigh I: " + i + " : " + arr[i]);
            Debug.Print "RelHigh I:" & i & " : " & arr(i)
            rng.Cells(i, 1).Font.Color = RGB(0, 200, 0)
            rng.Cells(i, 1).Font.Bold = True
            rng.Cells(i, 2) = "relHigh"

            If (arr(i) > highest) Then
                highestHigh.Add arr(i)
                highest = arr(i)
                highestRow = i
                'System.out.println("HH I: " + i + " : " + arr[i]);
                Debug.Print "HH I:" & i & " : " & arr(i)
            End If
        End If

        If (arr(i) < arr(i + 1)) And (arr(i) < arr(i - 1)) Then
            relLow.Add arr(i)
            rng.Cells(i, 1).Font.Color = vbRed
            'System.out.println("RelLow I: " + i + " : " + arr[i]);
            Debug.Print "RelLow I:" & i & " : " & arr(i)
            rng.Cells(i, 1).Font.Color = RGB(200, 0, 0)
            rng.Cells(i, 1).Font.Bold = True
            rng.Cells(i, 2) = "relLow"

            If (arr(i) < lowest) Then
                lowestLow.Add arr(i)
                lowest = arr(i)
                lowestRow = 1
                'System.out.println("HH I: " + i + " : " + arr[i]);
                Debug.Print "LL I:" & i & " : " & arr(i)
            End If
        End If
        ' store latest
        If (arr(i) = highest) Then highestRow = i
        If (arr(i) = lowest) Then lowestRow = i

    Next
    'highest / lowest
    rng.Cells(highestRow, 2) = "hestHigh"
    rng.Cells(lowestRow, 2) = "lestLow"

    ' return relHigh collection as an array
    Dim arrOut() As Integer
    ReDim arrOut(1 To relHigh.Count, 1 To 1)
    For i = 1 To relHigh.Count
        Debug.Print i, relHigh(i)
        arrOut(i, 1) = relHigh(i)
     Next
     sequence = arrOut

End Function
```

Comment: one more question: Where (how) would you change the color (red-low /green-high) of the actual cell that makes the high/low in your code?.  Thanks again

Comment: @jorge Assuming you've not changed the standard palette try `rng.offset(i-1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3` (red) or 4 (green)

Comment: Sorry, I feel quite useless in VBA, but I do not see where to put that. Thanks anyway!!!